# Linear Algebra(vector space,subspace)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

Let $$U=\{(x,x,y,y)∈\mathbb{F}^4:x,y∈\mathbb{F}\}$$Find a subspace $W$ of $ \mathbb{F}^4$ make $\mathbb{F}^4=U⊕W$

Comment: I think it's better to use LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $U= span \{(1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1)\}.$

Try $W= span \{(1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,1)\}.$

Comment: Thank you very much,I will use LaTex next time.